# c# cscore how to instantly play loopback capture recorded bytes

Tags: c#, playback, cscore

Yo guys, its me again with my noob questions. so this time I've used cscore to record windows sounds then send the recorded bytes to another pc by sockets and let them play there.

I just could not figure out how to play the gotten bytes under DataAvailable callback...

I've tried to write the bytes gotten to a file and play that file that worked but sound is not playing correctly like there's some unexpected sounds being heard with it too.

so here's my code:

```
WasapiCapture capture = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();
capture.Initialize();
capture.DataAvailable += (s, e) =>
{
    WaveWriter w = new WaveWriter("file.mp3", capture.WaveFormat);
    w.Write(e.Data, e.Offset, e.ByteCount);
    w.Dispose();
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("file.mp3"));
    SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(stream);
    player.Play();
    stream.Dispose();
};
capture.Start();
```

any help would be highly appreciated ;-;.
if you wanna hear how sound comes out by that way I would record you the result.

NOTE: if I just record sounds to a file and open later it just works perfectly but if I write and play instantly it unexpected sounds being heard.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SoundInSource` as an adapater.

```
var capture = new WasapiCapture(...)
capture.Initialize(); //initialize always first!!!!

var soundInSource = new SoundInSource(capture)
    { FillWithZeros = true }; //set FillWithZeros to true, to prevent WasapiOut from stopping for the case WasapiCapture does not serve any data

var soundOut = new WasapiOut();
soundOut.Initialize(soundInSource);
soundOut.Play();
```